# type error for practice interview question C++ (AlgoExpert )

Tags: c++

I need some help with a practice interview question I was working on earlier. I think I have a correct solution, but I'm getting a type error message which I'm not sure how to fix. I want to say it might be based on how the interface I'm using to test my code is formatted, but I'm not sure. Any suggestions?

Here is the full question below, followed by my code and the error message.  I am using the ASCII table integer values interchangeable with char characters to try and answer this question.

[image]

```cpp
using namespace std;

string caesarCypherEncryptor(string str, int key) {
  // Write your code here.
    
    int total;
    int index= 0;
    int rem;
    char val;

    
    for(char el: str)
    {
        total = (int)el + key;
        if(total > 122)
        {
            rem = (total - 122); 
    
            val = (char) (97 + rem);
            //cout<< "value type for case #1 --> "<< typeid(val).name() << " \n"; 
          //cout<< "index type for case #1 --> "<< typeid(str[index]).name() << " \n"; 
            str[index] = val;
        }
        else if(total < 122) {
            str[index] = (char)total;
        }
        index+=1;
    }
  return str;
```

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::detail::type_error'
  what():  [json.exception.type_error.316] invalid UTF-8 byte at index 0: 0x81
Aborted
exit status 134
```

Comment: There is nothing in the posted code which could cause a `json.exception`. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66647765/edit) the question and add the minimal, self contained code to duplicate the issue.

Comment: You don't need to use magic values such as `97` and `122`. You can inline `'a'` and `'z'` and the compiler will interpret them as their ascii values.

Answer (score -1):

This may not answer your question, but there's all kinds of logic and style improvements that could be made. Namely:

1. Don't inline magic values like 97 and 122. You can use the char constants `'a'` and `z` respectively.  Ditto for `'A'` and `'Z'`.
2. Use the modulo operator `%` to do the wraparound logic without specifically checking to see if `el+key` goes past the end of the alphabet.
3. Pass strings by const reference unless you intend to modify them inplace.
4. `key` was referenced in the problem as being non-negative. So go for unsigned parameters.

Without error checking (assumes all chars are lowercase `a-z`), the entire function could be simplified to this;

```
string caesarCypherEncryptor(const string& str, unsigned int key)
{
    const unsigned int ALPHABET_LENGTH = 26;
    string result;

    for (char c : str)
    {
       char x = 'a' + (((c-'a') + key)%ALPHABET_LENGTH);
       result += x;
    }
    return result;
}
```